# Char* p, and scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have been trying to look for a reason why the following code is failing, and I couldn't find one.
So please, excuse my ignorance and let me know what's happening here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
char* p="Hi, this is not going to work";
scanf("%s",p);
return 0;
}
```

As far as I understood, I created a pointer p to a contiguous area in the memory of the size 29 + 1(for the \0).
Why can't I use scanf to change the contents of that?

P.S Please correct me If I said something wrong about char*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
char* p="Hi, this is not going to work";
```

this does not allocate memory for you to write

this creates a `String Literal` which results in`Undefined Behaviour` every time you try to change its contents.

to use `p` as a buffer for your `scanf` do something like
`char * p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128); // 128 is an Example`

OR

you could as well do:

```
char p[]="Hi, this is not going to work";
```

Which I guess is what you really wanted to do.

Keep in mind that this can still end up being `UB` because `scanf()` does not check whether the place you are using is indeed valid writable memory.

remember :

`char * p` is a String Literal and should not be modified

`char p[] = "..."` allocates enough memory to hold the String inside the `"..."` and may be changed (its contents I mean).

**Edit :**

A nice trick to avoid `UB` is

```
char * p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
scanf("%126s",s);
```

Comment: If that's the case, then how do I read a string with unknown length?

Comment: @Adel, made a small Edit, look last line

Comment: That's nice, thanks! But, what to do if I can't predict the length of the string to be scanned?

Comment: @Adel, you may not read a line with Unknown Length, but you may use a very big buffer (eg. `buffer[1024]`) but still make sure that you don't overflow that big buffer

Comment: @Muggen: Just checked something now char*p="Hi"; then I wrote p ="lol" and the code worked just fine, how did it edit the string if it was readonly? Thanks

Comment: @Adel, the String is not read-only. Just because it does not crash it does not mean it is right. This is what `Undefined Behaviour` means. Anything may happen :)

Comment: To add, declaring a non-const pointer `char *p="abc";` to a string literal is bad practice. When using immutable string literals, declare them as `const char *`. Then the compiler will inform you, should you accidentally pass that pointer to a function expecting a non-const pointer argument. Search for "const correctness" to read about the concept, and why it is important.

Comment: @Muggen: Oh alright!Thanks!! That makes me wonder though, if char*p gives UB everytime when we try to mess with it, why would we ever use it?

Comment: @Adel, `char * p` does not give UB. It is a pointer, which points to a location we can use to write. If we use **that location** in a bad way, then it is UB.

Comment: @Adel, by doing `p = "lol"` you did not edit the string literal pointed to by `p`. You changed the pointer `p` to point to another string literal.

Comment: @mizo, which would make someone wonder if in such cases he should use `const char * const p = "This is a String";` :P

Comment: @Adel, also if you wanted to change what `p` points to you should use `strcpy()` which again can cause `UB` if you exceed allowed limits. And assuming that `p` is a valid pointer to use.

Comment: @Muggen, indeed, if they wish to prohibit changes to the pointer's address value. This isn't obligatory, though, like having a plain `char *` ever pointing to a string literal is a no-no in my book.

Comment: is 'scanf("%126s",s)' right? actually '  char p[MAX_SIZE]; fgets(p,MAX_SIZE,stdin)' is a better choice.

Answer (score 6):

`p` points to a constant literal, which may in fact reside in a read-only memory area (implementation dependent). At any rate, trying to overwrite that is **undefined behaviour**. I.e. it might result in nothing, or an immediate crash, or a hidden memory corruption which causes mysterious problems much later. **Don't ever do that**.

Comment: @Peter, I didn't downvote but dont see a reason as to why -1 so I +1

Comment: I just removed my down vote. I saw some other explanation earlier. I guess you edited this.

Comment: Note that changing the declaration to `char p[] = "Hi, this is not going to work";` *does* create a modifiable buffer that the OP can use.

Comment: @Muggen, very kind of you :-) Now that the downvote is removed, feel free to remove your compensating upvote, as your answer is much better (it deserves the top spot so +1 from me)

Comment: @user210504, yes I've been editing my answer to improve it. I believe I haven't changed the meaning of it, but please check the edit history and let me know if I wrote anything incorrect in some earlier version. @John, thanks. It's always good to polish my rusty C skills a bit :-)

Comment: @Peter, I will leave the +1 for mentioning that string literals behaviour is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because memory has not been allocated for p. Allocate memory for p and it should be ok. What you have is a constant memory area pointing to by p. When you attempt to write something in this data segment, the runtime environment will raise a trap which will lead to a crash.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score -2):

`scanf()` parses data entered from stdin (normally, the keyboard). I think you want `sscanf()`.

However, the purpose of `scanf()` is to part a string with predefined escape sequences, which your test string doesn't have. So that makes it a little unclear exactly what you are trying to do.

Note that `sscanf()` takes an additional argument as the first argument, which specifies the string being parsed.

Comment: I think the question is why scanf is not working. Answer by Muggen explain that

Comment: I see several things wrong with the OP's code, so it's a little hard to know exactly what he was trying to accomplish.