# Scanf for char *path

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read from keyboard (using `scanf`) the variable `char *path`
I don't know how to pass the `path` as argument of scanf to get the input from keyboard. How can I do it?

P.S. This is what I have tried:

```
char *filePath = "";
printf("Path: "); scanf("%s", &filePath);
```

But my application always stops.

Comment: instead of downvoting, you could have explained me...

Comment: I downvoted because the question shows no research effort. It is [trivial to google for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=scanf+string).

Comment: I searched on google, but I didn't find what I needed, so I considered it is better to post here. I am a newbie with pointers. I am learning about them currently... So, can you please remove your downvote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Char\* p, and scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900394/char-p-and-scanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First allocate enough space for `filePath`, then pass it without `&`:

```
char filePath[128];
printf("Path: ");
scanf("%127s", filePath);
```

Another way is using `malloc`:

```
char *filePath = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
...
free(filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char *filePath = "";
```

Compiler should have warned you for the above statement. `filePath` type is `const char*` and not `char*`.

`filePath` is pointing to an empty string literal. String literals reside in read only location and you can not edit them.

You have to allocate and memory using `malloc` and then take input. Once you are done, you need to `free` it.

Comment: Why do you recommend use of `malloc` over a stack variable?

Comment: Also, being a bit nit-picky, string literals *may* reside in read-only memory.  This isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @simonc Yeah. I should recommended stack variable. I think it's fine in this case. I agree with your second comment but on most of the architectures, string literals reside in read-only segment.

Comment: Compilers should not warn about assigning a string literal to a `char *`. It's a special case of `const`-removal that is explicitly allowed due to `const`'s late addition to the C language.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *filePath = "";
```

declares a pointer to a string literal which contains only a nul terminator.  This may exist in read-only memory so can't be modified.  You need a larger, writeable string instead

```
char filePath[200];
if (scanf("%199s", filePath) != 1) {
    /* user didn't enter a string */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanf method ALWAYS uses a reference to the variable you're writing into (so by non-pointer variables you use the & to get the reference (memory address)).
Since you are using a pointer, the pointer itself is already a reference to the variable, it points to the memory address of the variable, hence no need for the & usage.

Just be sure to always allocate enough space for the input string.
The (ANSI)C way is to use malloc(), the newer (C++ and later C standards) ay is to create an array using `new arrayname[size]` .